# Measurement system analysis

Tags: measurement-error

Let's say I'm responsible for checking the length of shoes on a production line. Our production system isn't great, so a shoe that should be 25 cm long might actually be a slightly different length (25.4, 24.8, 26.0, etc.) And I am measuring with a set of rulers that are not great, so I could measure 25.0 cm when the actual shoe length is different (24.9, 25.1 cm, etc.). When I'm measuring shoes on the production line, I might pick up any of the 5 rulers in the set. How can I answer the question, "What is the **smallest real difference in length that I can resolve** with these not-great rulers?" Assume I only have time to measure each shoe on the production line once, so I can't eliminate the non-biased error by making multiple measurements. Also I'm the only inspector, so we can ignore variability due to different operators.

For example, could I take a shoe, measure it with my 5 not-great rulers, calculate the round-robin difference between each ruler to all the others, repeat for several other shoes of different lengths, average all the length differences, and say that this average is the smallest difference in length I can resolve?

(Also is there a name for this kind of analysis, maybe a flavor of gage R&R? Knowing the name would help me read up on suggested approaches, since I know this is not a novel problem.)

Comment: If on the whole the rulers are unbiased and provide independent measurements, the answer is "as small as you want:" just repeat the measurements. Because you have taken some effort to describe a context, I would suggest the *best* solution would be developed in conjunction with a specific set of quality control targets and a proposed QC system.  The considerations should include the costs of making each measurement and the costs of making incorrect decisions (letting off-spec shoes out, fixing apparent off-spec shoes that are the correct lengths, or taking other actions to correct the system).

Comment: Excellent point! I edited the question to say that repeating measurements is not an option, due to time limits on the production line. The ruler errors are unbiased, as are the production errors causing the shoe length variation. I am seeking to define the quality control target, which it seems can't be smaller than the overall measurement system error. Do you have a recommended reference for estimating this overall error, or even a name for the right technique to do so? It differs from traditional [gage R&R](https://quality-one.com/grr/), right?

Comment: At first blush, the presence of measurement error shouldn't matter: it just becomes one component of overall production variability.  Your target remains the same and control limits become a little wider due to the measurement error.  As a consequence it might take a little longer to detect an out-of-control situation or, if the rulers are really bad (especially if repeated measurements are not independent), you might be unable to achieve your QC targets at all because you just cannot tell the difference between good product and poor product.

Comment: I believe I will be doing an [Extended Gage R&R](https://www.qualitymag.com/articles/90918-the-expanded-gage-rr-study) study, where there is an additional source of variability besides part and operator, namely gage error. Instead of rulers in my simple example, in reality I am using a set of noisy instruments to measure the part. And though my example had a single operator (me), in reality I may have to consider variability due to different operators doing the inspection.